# Merge [vibrate] and [vibration]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Please also see [These tags are giving me a bad vibe (merge request)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357326/these-tags-are-giving-me-a-bad-vibe-merge-request)

I just noticed that we have [vibrate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vibrate) and [vibration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vibration) with 212 and 130 posts respectively as of this posting.

Can these two tags be merged into just a single [vibration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vibration) tag with [vibrate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vibrate) being made a synonym?

Comment: Is any of these tags actually necessary? Really?

Comment: There's also the chance of a [tag:html-vibration] appearing as [that is an API](https://www.w3.org/TR/vibration/), so merging them all together is a good idea.

Comment: @KenY-N Great, now those "VIRUS FOUND" scams will get even *more* annoying...

Answer (score -1):

Neither of these should be a tag in the first place.

Vibration is a minor feature of a number of different mobile development frameworks. Each one of them is different enough that it makes no sense to combine them all into a single tag -- familiarity with iOS vibration APIs  won't help you answer questions about the equivalent on Android, for instance.

Comment: Familiarity with iOS strings won't help you answer questions about the equivalent on Android either, we still have a strings tag, and an arrays tag, etc. etc. Vibration **means the same thing in all contexts**. I can't think of a meaning for vibration other than... to vibrate, so it is not ambiguous.

Comment: Please take discussions about the merits (or lack there of) for platform specific vibration tags to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357326/these-tags-are-giving-me-a-bad-vibe-merge-request?noredirect=1&lq=1 Let's keep this discussion specific to vibrate and vibration. Thanks.

Comment: @TinyGiant There's a pretty big difference there. It's possible to ask a language-independent question about basic data structures like strings or arrays. The same is not true of vibration.

Comment: You may want to check out [What is the process for tag removal (burnination)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/4639281) which also outlines when it should be removed. You may notice that nowhere does it say that tags should be removed if no language-independent questions can be asked about the concept.

Comment: I agree. We don't need another tag for a vibration API. More relevant will be to tag the question with android/ios or any other possible tags and you'll get the best answers from the community.